# It is taking too long to create a subsite in SharePoint online using custom template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, template

I have a custom site template, When I am creating a sub site using this custom template then it continue to show `working on it` and it does not stop.

But when I go to site content, the site shows created but the page keeps showing `working on it`.

What could be the main reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 2):

does the custom template have customization (css, js files etc)? Can you check directly layouts pages of the new site like settings.aspx, permission (user, people, group) etc? If they are loading properly and created on time then there will be some issues while loading site Home/Default page. 
When new site starts to load, after couple of minutes, open the browser developer tool (preferable chrome) and check the errors there, you will get some clue.